# Power flow to create a CSV table from two sharepoint lists based on a reference

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, csv, export-to-excel, loop

I have two lists in sharepoint, need export but problem is with data from second list. Export needs datas from both lists.

LIST A contains Name, Surname, Age
LIST B contains Name, Hobbies, Sports, Info

My goal is create export with all datas together. The condition is when Name from LIST A is a same from the LIST B

Export csv: `Name, surname, Age, Name, Hobbies,Sports, Info`

I tryed putting both List append to the arrays and after with loop condition

if `item()?['Name'] is equal item()?['Name']`

and add hobbies to variable with `setProperty(setProperty(item(), 'Name', items('Apply_to_each')?['Name']),'Hobbies','')`

I don't know if I'm on the right track, because this operation ends after ten minutes in timeout

Comment: What is the issue, are you getting any error or wrong values in exported file? Can you add screenshot of flow and sample list data if possible?

Comment: Also, I think you need to change this expression: `item()?['Name'] is equal item()?['Name']`. Instead of using `item()`, use in this format: `items('Apply_to_each_2')` and `items('Apply_to_each')`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I solved it by converting both ````Lists```` objects to XML and using ````xpath```` from ````List 1```` to ````LIST 2```` and then creating a final table that is combined from both`.